# If $a_i\geq 0,$ prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}$diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

If $a_i\geq0,a_n\not\equiv 0,$ prove  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}$ diverges.

I have known that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$converges, then  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}}$converges, but how can I prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}$ diverges?

Sincerely thanks for your help.

> > Add : Such stupid as I am, we do not need the condition $\sum a_n$ converges.

Strictly, rewrite $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}=\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}\geq a_k\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty\frac 1n\to 
\infty$, where $a_k$ is the first $a_i\neq 0$.

Comment: The $n$-th partial sum is clearly greater than $\sum_{i=1}^n a_1/i = a_1\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$.

Comment: How do you prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}}$ converge? Thanks.

Comment: @Hans,The provement may be long and Will I type them here?

Comment: I have opened a question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228749/convergence-of-averging-series. You may post your answer there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose $a_{n_0}\neq 0$, then for all $n\geq n_0$, 
$$\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}\geq a_{n_0}\times\frac{1}{n}$$
hence diverges since the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: What is $\;a_{n_0}\;$ and how come that mean is greater than $\;a_{n_0}\cdot\frac1n\;$ ??

Comment: Why is $a_i \ge a_{n_0}$?

Comment: Just discard all terms except $a_{n_0}$, and since they are positive...

Comment: Ah, my fault. I totally misread your statement.

Comment: Wow, after seeing this answer I feel incredibly stupid.