# Convergence of averging series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges where $a_n>0,\ \forall n\in\mathbb N$, prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}}$ converge.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i}{n}$ diverges, so one can not use the bound of the GM-AM relation at least directly.

Comment: You have, of course, a *positive* sequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ to form those series there, right?

Comment: @user2566092: I have added my failed tries. Would you like to withdraw your downvote?

Comment: @Timbuc: Yes, thank you. I have added the positivity of $a_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$\displaystyle  \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i} \geq \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{-1}}$$ it suffices to prove the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$.

This follows directly from [Carleman's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_inequality)

Comment: What do you mean ? Convergence follows from these bounds and comparison test

Comment: How does this prove the needed convergence? The partial sum of the second term diverges.

Comment: huh ? What second term ?

Comment: Like I said before, "the partial sum of the second term (expression) diverges." Do you not agree? If you do, bounding by divergent series does not say anything about convergence.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the confusion, you were right. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}}$ converges is equal to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n}$ converges.

$Firstly,$if $b_{n+1}\geqslant b_n$for any $b_i$, we have

$b_1+\cdots+b_{2n-1}\geqslant b_n+\cdots+_{2n-1}\geqslant nb_n$

$$\Longrightarrow\frac{2n-1}{b_1+\cdots+b_{2n-1}}+\frac{2n}{b_1+\cdots+b_{2n}}\leqslant\frac{2n-1}{nb_n}+\frac{2n}{nb_n}\leqslant\frac{4}{b_n}=4a_n$$
$$\Longrightarrow\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n}\leqslant4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}$$
$Secondly,$ arrange {$b_n$}, make it increase, and then we get {$c_n$},for any $n$,we have $$c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_n\leqslant b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n}\leqslant\frac{n}{c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_n}$$
$\quad\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_n}$ converges , so $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n}$ converges.

**Add:**
since $a_n\to 0$ , for any $\varepsilon>0$, exist a $N$,while $n>N$, we have $a_n<\varepsilon$, similarly, for any $A>0$, exist a $N$,while $n>N$, we have $b_n>A$, that is to say, there are finite number of $b_i\leqslant A$, so I can take out the  minimum and the second minimum and so on.

**Besides**, for I have proved that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n}$ converges, after my arrangement of it, it's limit will not change, so $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n}$.

According to $Firstly$ and $Secondly$, We get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n}$ converges.
$viz.\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}}$ converges.

Another Carleman's inequality,my proof is similar to LeGrandDODOM's hyperlink.

Comment: Nice proof. It will be better if you state and show explicitly that rearrangement as a sequence $\{c_n\}$ of the sequence $\{b_n\}$ does exist, or in other words, there is a minimum for $\{b_n\}$ and second minimum, third ...

Comment: Good. Also you need to state that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{c_n}$ converges (in fact to the same  limit as $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$).

Comment: Shouldn't you say $\{a_n\}$ converges TO ZERO in your "Add"? Also do you not agree with my last comment?

Comment: You have adopted the point on $a_n$ converging to zero, but not that of the convergence of $\sum\limits \frac{1}{c_n}$ (to $\sum\limits a_n$). I originally thought it was you who rejected the edit. It is good that you tell me it was not the case. I am not that experienced with the site either. I now looked up the reason for rejection. It said my edit conflicted with a subsequent edit. Perhaps I edited it just when you were doing the same.

Comment: No, you got it backwards. You need the convergence of $\sum\frac{1}{c_n}$ to derive the convergence of $\sum_n\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^nc_n}$.