# Does harmonic mean of a convergent series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Given $a_n>0$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.
Let $$A_m=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_n\ ,\ B_m=\frac{m}{\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_n^{-1}}$$
representing arithmetic mean and harmonic mean.It's trivial that $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m$ is not convergent.However, does $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}B_m$ converge?And if we define
$$H_{m}^{s}=\left(\frac{a_1^s+a_2^s+\cdots+a_m^s}{m}\right)^{\frac{1}{s}}$$
where $s\neq0$. Can we find all values of $s$ that makes $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}H_{m}^{s}$ converge?

Comment: For large $m$ I think the terms will start to look like $1/m$, so I have a feeling the final sum does not converge.

Comment: Is it trivial that $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}A_m$ is not convergent? I don't see it yet, perhaps I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @MartinR As $a_n>0$ we have $A_m >a_1/m$ which diverges.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: Yes, of course.

Comment: Then $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}H_{m}^{s}$ “trivially” diverges for $s \ge 1$. Convergence for $s \le 0$ (and in particular for $\sum B_m$) is demonstrated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1228749/42969.

Comment: The case $0 < s < 1$ is treated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2587408/42969.